# Wordpress causes Mysql high memory

Tags: mysql, memory

Recenty I deployed a wordpress multisite instance by helm chart to GKE.
However, It causes increasing memory of mysql from 600MB to 2.6G usage. I try to use Percona to analyze the database, then see that below query has been executed 60 times per each second to mysql instance, even no traffic to wordpress site yet.

```
"SELECT
  `option_value`
FROM
  `wp_options`
WHERE
  `option_name` = ?
LIMIT
  ?"
```

What should I do now? Thanks.